# Matrix class with overloaded `operator[]`

Tags: c++, matrix, c++14

I have implemented a Matrix class that allocates memory using `unique_ptr`. How to make it more diverse and optimized in terms of memory usage and efficiency?

```
//
// Created by Mayukh Sarkar on 26/12/19.
//

#ifndef DP2_MATRIX_H
#define DP2_MATRIX_H


#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T>
class Matrix {
private:
    size_t row{};
    size_t col{};
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> data;
public:
    explicit Matrix(size_t row, size_t col, T def) {
        // Create a matrix of row X col and initialize
        // each element of the matrix with def
        this->row = row;
        this->col = col;
        this->data = std::make_unique<T[]>(this->row * this->col);
        std::fill_n(data.get(), row*col, def);
    }

    // Overload the [] operator for the 2d array like access
    T* operator[](int r) {
        if (r >= row) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Can not access out of bound element!");
        }
        return &this->data[r*col];
    }

    // Overload the << operator for console logging
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, Matrix &mObj) {
        auto shape = mObj.shape();
        for(int i=0; i< shape.first; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<shape.second; j++) {
                os << mObj[i][j] << " ";
            }
            os << "\n";
        }
        return os;
    }

    // Set all the values of the Matrix
    void setValues(T value) {
        std::fill_n(data.get(), row*col, value);
    }

    // Get row and col values
    std::pair<size_t, size_t> shape() const {
        return std::make_pair(this->row, this->col);
    }
};

#endif //DP2_MATRIX_H
```

I want to specifically optimize the `[]operator` overloading because I feel it is not good to handle pointers directly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

### Pragma once

Instead of

```
#ifndef DP2_MATRIX_H
#define DP2_MATRIX_H
```

consider using

```
#pragma once
```

Once is non-standard, but supported by all compilers supporting
C++14 and reduces compilation times.

### Includes

On MSVC, `#include <stdexcept>` is needed for the `out_of_range`
error. I also think your include lines look tidier if you sort them in
alphabetical order. :)

### Bounds checking

```
Matrix<int>(10, 10, 0)[10][0]
```

Is an error that will be detected by your bounds checking, but

```
Matrix<int>(10, 10, 0)[0][10]
```

is the same type of error, but won't be detected. Consider following
the STL convention described in [this Stackoverflow
answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026042/when-implementing-operator-how-should-i-include-bounds-checking). That
is, you remove bounds checking from `operator[]` but add a method `at`
which does bounds checking for both dimensions.

### Const correctness

You should add `const` declared variants of the accessors. You can
also add it to the parameters, but imho, that is not as useful.

Result:

```
#pragma once

#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename T>
class Matrix {
private:
    size_t row{};
    size_t col{};
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> data;
    void boundscheck(int r, int c) const {
        if (!(0 <= r && r < row && 0 <= c && c < col)) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Can not access out of bound element!");
        }
    }
public:
    // Set all the values of the Matrix
    void setValues(T value) {
        std::fill_n(data.get(), row*col, value);
    }
    explicit Matrix(size_t row, size_t col, T def) {
        // Create a matrix of row X col and initialize
        // each element of the matrix with def
        this->row = row;
        this->col = col;
        this->data = std::make_unique<T[]>(this->row * this->col);
        setValues(def);
    }
    // Overload the [] operator for the 2d array like access
    T* operator[](int r) {
        return &this->data[r * col];
    }
    const T* operator[](int r) const {
        return &this->data[r * col];
    }
    T& at(int r, int c) {
        boundscheck(r, c);
        return this->data[r * col + c];
    }
    const T& at(int r, int c) const {
        boundscheck(r, c);
        return this->data[r * col + c];
    }
    // Overload the << operator for console logging
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, Matrix &mObj) {
        auto shape = mObj.shape();
        for(int i=0; i< shape.first; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<shape.second; j++) {
                os << mObj[i][j] << " ";
            }
            os << "\n";
        }
        return os;
    }
    // Get row and col values
    std::pair<size_t, size_t> shape() const {
        return std::make_pair(this->row, this->col);
    }
};
```

I don't think it is possible to make a general matrix class consume less memory or run quicker than that. Compilers generate pretty good code for the accessor functions. You probably have to use a different data type such as a sparse matrix to improve performance much.

Comment: It is really a shame that C++ doesn't have anything that can enforce OutOfBoud access with `[] operator` or even `[][] operator`. Anyway nice solutions.

Comment: @MayukhSarkar For that, you use `.at()`. Also, `.operator()()` is common for multi-dimensional indexing.

Comment: @Deduplictor Yeah but a [][] operator would have been nice. Wonder how boost does it?

Comment: @MayukhSarkar You can fake it using nested classes. But imo, you shouldn't do it. It makes the code harder to understand for no tangible benefit.

Comment: @MayukhSarkar If you're creating an overload of `operator[]`, you can include range checks in it, but that is not the norm.  Some compilers include range checks in `operator[]` when building debug versions.

Comment: You should make input for `operator[]` and function `at` of type `size_t` - so on definition it is clear that you don't accept negative values. It will also fix a few casting warnings and some when user misuses `operator []`.

Comment: @ALX23z Yes, or `unsigned`. The reason I didn't add it is because I've seen different sources use different types for the parameter to `operator[]`. Some use `int`, others `unsigned` or `size_t` so I wasn't sure would be the best.

Comment: The thing is that it should coincide with `rows / cols` type whatever it is.